# Dynamic add multi fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am beginner in javascript. I need to dynamic add multifields in existing form that have same id.

first fields has this name :

```
<input type="text" name="myInputs[0][address]">
<input type="text" name="myInputs[0][whitelist]">
```

And when clicking "Add another text input" I want a new fields with

```
<input type="text" name="myInputs[1][address]">
<input type="text" name="myInputs[1][whitelist]">
```

and clicking again on "Add another text input"

```
<input type="text" name="myInputs[2][address]">
<input type="text" name="myInputs[2][whitelist]">
```

When submit post only the first fields are posted :

```
<input type="text" name="myInputs[0][address]">
<input type="text" name="myInputs[0][whitelist]">
```

Here the code :

```
       <script>
            var counter = 1;
            var limit = 10;

            function addInput(divName){
                if (counter == limit)  {
                    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
                }
                else {
                    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                    newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs["+ (counter + 1) +"][address]'><input type='text' name='myInputs["+ (counter + 1) +"][whitelist]'>";
                    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        </script>

             <div id="dynamicInput">
                       Entry 1<br>
                                  <input type="text" name="myInputs[0][address]">
                                  <input type="text" name="myInputs[0][whitelist]">
             </div>
             <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

Comment: Add your `post` javascript also

Comment: your code seems to work fine

Comment: Everything looks fine.Post full form contents along with submit button